# is it possible to use the wheel button without using freeglut?

Tags: glut, freeglut

I've heard somewhere that it's possible to use the wheel button by comparing the button variable to (3 / 4), but it seems that no events are triggered whenever i spin the wheel button.
what am i doing wrong here? i'm trying to avoid freeglut.

Comment: Did you do it like illustrated in the first answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378/using-the-mouse-scrollwheel-in-glut)

Comment: i reviewed @BentFX answer, but nothing happens when i roll the wheel button, i even tried to put a break point at the beginning of the MouseFunc() function, still nothing happened.

Comment: i also reviewed the following link : http://www.realmtech.net/opengl/glut.php but couldn't understand how to apply the 'patch' command on windows

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid FreeGLUT? It's the only distro of GLUT that's still being supported; it's the only distro of GLUT that you should ever *use*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the middle button, you can try GetAsyncKeyState()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx

Example:

```
//Test if middle mouse button is pressed
if(GetAsyncKeyState(4)<-30000){
    //do something
    }
```

Comment: PS: You need to include windows.h