# glutMouseWheelFunc doesnt trigger callback

Tags: opengl, glut, freeglut

I am trying to implement  zoom in or zoom out operations using mouse scroll button
by **`glutMouseWheelFunc`**  in `opengl` . I have implemted the code as below :

```
#include<GL/freeglut.h>

void mouseWheel(int button, int dir, int x, int y)
{

    printf("in mouse wheel \n");

    if (dir > 0)
    {
        // Zoom in
        ztrans = ztrans - 1.0;
        printf("scroll in = %0.3f\n ",ztrans);
    }
    else
    {
        // Zoom out
        ztrans = ztrans + 1.0;
        printf("scroll out = %0.3f\n ",ztrans);
    }

        glutPostRedisplay();

}

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
      // general initializations
      glutInit(&argc, argv);
      glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
      glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
      glutInitWindowSize(800, 400);
      glutCreateWindow("Rotation");

      // register callbacks
      glutReshapeFunc(changeSize); 
      glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
      glutIdleFunc(renderScene);
      glutIgnoreKeyRepeat(1);
      glutMouseFunc(mouseButton); 
      glutMotionFunc(mouseMove); 
      glutMouseWheelFunc(mouseWheel); // Register mouse wheel function

      glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

      glutMainLoop();
      return 0;
```

}

On executing, it is not calling the registered callback function(`mouseWheel`) . My system has freeglut3 installed.

Comment: What operating system are you developing on? I just tried this on my Ubuntu 12.04 with freeglut and it worked fine. Do the other mouse callbacks work?

Comment: I tried it in Ubuntu 13.04 . Yes other mouse callbacks are working fine.

Comment: There may be window manager settings in Ubuntu 13 which reserve the mouse wheel for scrolling virtual desktops or something. Check your preferences. If that isn't it, I'm out of ideas

Comment: See this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378/using-the-mouse-scrollwheel-in-glut][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378/using-the-mouse-scrollwheel-in-glut

Answer (score 1):

try using 
a `static int` inside `void mouseWheel`method, and then use it in `renderScene` 
like this

```
static int k;
static int ztrans
void mouseWheel(int button, int dir, int x, int y)
{

   k = dir; // int dir is +1 of -1 based on the direction of the wheel motion

   ztrans = ztrans + k;

}
```

This worked for me,
Try this and feedback, GoodLuck .